# How to bind socket to local addreess with TCPv6

Tags: sockets, winapi, tcp

I have to port existing Win API application to work with TCPv6. Can't figure out how to bind socket to localhost.

Earlier was:

```html
struct sockaddr_in ServerAddress;
ListenSocket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
...
ServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
ServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
ServerAddress.sin_port = htons(nPortNo);
```

Now, I'm trying:

```html
    struct sockaddr_in ServerAddress;
    ListenSocket = WSASocket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
    ...
    ServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET6;
    ServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("::1");
    ServerAddress.sin_port = htons(nPortNo);
```

And bind returns SOCKET_ERROR

There is a page from MS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but there is no bind example

Comment: `inet_addr` returns an unsigned long, exactly how are you expecting that to fit an IPv6 address?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 ServerAddress;
ListenSocket = WSASocket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
...
ServerAddress.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
if (InetPton(AF_INET6, "::1", sockAddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr) != 1) printf("error, inet_pton() failed!\n");
ServerAddress.sin6_port = htons(nPortNo);
```

Comment: You can use the `in6addr_any` constant instead of using `InetPton()`.  Another option is to use `getaddrinfo()` instead.  But yes, either way, you do need to use `sockaddr_in6` instead of `sockaddr_in`.

Comment: Binding to in6addr_any makes the port available on all network interfaces, not just the loopback interface.  (That might be okay, depending on what you're trying to do, but it's not quite the same thing as binding the socket to localhost, which is what the question asked for)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `in6addr_loopback` instead, which is defined as the `::1` address.